# Stars moved positions

Tags: multiple-star-systems

I have just witnessed 2 stars change positions from above the dominant star to the east of my location. Stratford-upon-Avon 
They moved off 1 by 1 and drifted away perfectly parallel to each other then disappeared. How.
This is the second time in 2 days that different stars have moved.
This happened at 8.15pm.

Comment: This doesn't quite fit the "line of lights" description but it surely is an observation of satellites, even if not the starlink constellation.